# Toggle inspector is not working when redux state is used in the app

Tags: react-native, redux

I am using `redux` in my application and I will access app state across all `.js` files in the app, app is also running fine normally. But when I am trying to open `Toggle Inspector`, getting `undefined is not an object error` as follows,

[image]

It's showing that `displayname` is undefined and this is how i am accessing `displayname`,

```
const { user: { displayname, profileimageurl }, selectedcompanyid, companyArray } = this.props;(this.props holds redux state)
```

If i remove `displayname` from above statement then it will show error about `profileimageurl` . If i remove this one also then error will be about next prop from the `redux` state. if i don't access `redux` state at all then `Toggle inspector` works well without any error. here my doubts are

1.How come it is matter to `Toggle Inspector` if any variable is undefined?

2.How come a variable is becoming undefined, only when trying to access `Toggle Inspector`?

3.How to resolve this and are there any tools available alternative to `Toggle Inspector` to inspect UI?

Comment: Well you are using js and you don't get the warning like in typescript that you data from redux can be undefined in the first render. So when you open toggle inspector it is getting that undefined so it crash. Try to use user?.displayname (if your js support it or you will need to check if user exist with simple if).

Comment: @anthonywillismuñoz if that is the case then it must give error when i run normally, right! why am i getting error only when 'Toggle Inspector' is turned on?